# Memory Usage Increase Approximately Double for Assigning 1

Tags: php

```
<?php
$array=[];
for($i=0;$i<=50000;$i++){
    $array[]=$i;
}
echo round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024,2)." MB".PHP_EOL;
//Output: 1.87 MB

$b=$array;
echo round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024,2)." MB".PHP_EOL;
//Output: 1.87 MB

$b[]=1;
echo round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024,2)." MB".PHP_EOL;
//Output: 3.37 MB

?>
```

When I assigned 1 in $b[], the memory usage increase to double.Why?

> Memory Usage may vary to other devices.

Comment: What would you expect to have happened?

Comment: @JeffUK I would imagine that the OP would expect adding another 50001 elements to an array containing 50001 elements would double the memory.  However, adding 1 element to the 50001 elements seems to double the memory.  It is as if the copying of `$array` to `$b` does not consume more memory, but as soon as the copied array is modified, the memory consumption suddenly calculates as expected.

Comment: Then the answer is a truism! If the question is "Why doesn't copying an array consume memory until that array is modified" the answer is "Because copying an array doesn't consume memory until that array is modified", Maybe OP expected it to triple, half, or do something else!

Comment: My guess is that assigning $b to $array just points $b to $array, but when you alter $b, the engine needs to make a copy of the array for $b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning $b to $array just points $b to $array in memory.

```
Memory:
                [ ]
$b => $array => [ ]
                [ ]
                [ ]
```

When you alter $b, the engine needs to make a copy of $array, add the array element, and point $b to it in a new memory slot.

```
Memory:
                [ ]
      $array => [ ]
                [ ]
          $b => [ ]
```